# Ayuda en guardar imagen en base de datos SQL MVC 5 y Entity 6.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

hola muy buenas a todos vengo a ustedes a pedirle ayuda que la verdad no se como resolverla he creado un CRD envisual studio 2013 que usa MVC 5 Y entity 6.0
como puedo subir una imagen desde mi CRUD creado con MVC5 y guardarla en una base de datos sql ya que pude revisar q al usar entity me cambio mi atributo que tenia imagen a byte[] y ahora no entiendo como puedo subir mi imagen y guardarla en mi base de datos 
tengo entendido que tengo q hacer una convercion pero no se como empesar 
espero una ayudar porfa se los agradeceria mucho
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
ahi esta mi modelo y en entity ps esta como tipo byte

Comment: Hola Hector, en lugar de la imagen coloca el código directamente

Comment: eso lo puse como referencia para q puedan ver el tipo de datos q tengo al usar entity pero dime q codigo quieres q coloque el del controlador o cual me pides

Comment: Todo el código que sea relevante, el código de la entidad y del controller estarían bien

Comment: La recomendación en almacenamiento de imágenes es la de guardar el archivo de imagen en un carpeta del servidor y solo guardar la ruta en tu base datos. Ahora, puede que tu requerimiento específico sea guardar la imagen en la base de datos, ahí si que necesitas verificar sobre como manejar la información con Entity Framework (justo la pregunta que haces).

Comment: si extacto amigo eso es lo que quiero hacer almacenar la imagen en una base de datos SQL y no la ruta de la imagen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una imagen no es mas que un arreglo de bytes, por lo que Entity Framework te lo convierte en ese tipo de propiedad. Lo que necesitas hacer para guardar la imagen que el usuario está tratando de subir es convertir tu campo input/file a un arreglo de bytes.

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <label for="file">Upload Image:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="width: 100%;" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="submit" />
}
```

Controller

```
    public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                file.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
                byte[] array = ms.GetBuffer();

                var context = new Models.BDEntities();
                context.activofijoes.Add(new Models.activofijo()
                {
                    FotoAF = array,
                });
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

        }

        return RedirectToAction("actionname", "controller");
    }
```

Adicionalmente, para mostrar tu imagen en la vista, te recomiendo crear un controlador que maneje el arreglo de imágenes y te regrese la imagen:

Controlller

```
public class ImagesController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        var context = new Models.DBEntities();
        byte[] imageData = context.activofijoes.FirstOrDefault(i => i.id == id)?.FotoAF;
        if (imageData != null)
        {
            return File(imageData, "image/png"); // Might need to adjust the content type based on your actual image type
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

View

```
<img src="@Url.Action("Index", "Images", new { id = 1 })" />
```